# i am getting NullReferenceException.can anyone help me. this code has done in c# CRM2013

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

i am getting `NullReferenceException` at

```
"tb = Page.FindControl("table1").FindControl("txtAccount" +i) as TextBox;"
```

can anyone help me this code has done in c# CRM2013.

```
if (accountEntity.Attributes.Contains("telephone1"))
   {
      string phone = accountEntity.Attributes["telephone1"].ToString();

      tb = Page.FindControl("table1").FindControl("txtAccount" +i) as TextBox;
              if (tb!= null)
              {
                  tb.Text = phone;
              }

    }
```

Comment: Which object is `null`?  Does `Page.FindControl("table1")` actually find anything?  Your code assumes it does, but if it doesn't then that's the exception you would get.

Comment: It's likely not finding a control named "tabel1"

Comment: I believe that a remark is due about how bad an idea it is to shove ASPX pages inside CRM (primary reason: it's not supported and bound to randomly break anytime the platform is upgraded)

Answer (score 1):

Your *NullReferenceException* isn't related to CRM. You are getting this error because this expression is returning null

```
Page.FindControl("table1")
```

So make sure you have an element on your page with the id `table1`.

Comment: again its getting error while i have changed as you said above..like as Page.FindControl("table1")

Comment: i want to set the text value to the textbox its id is txtAccount and my table id is table1.